# Debug app installation get blocked

Tags: android, debugging, installation, apk, warnings

[image]

Need to know why this  warning message occurred in debug.apk installation how to solve this issue? if any one know this issue please help me to solve this issue
and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51233170/421467

That says:

> Go to the link below and submit your application.
>
> [Play Protect Appeals Submission Form](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals)
>
> After a few days, the problem will be fixed