# Debug app blocked by play protect

Tags: android

When trying to install a debugging application, "Playback Protection Alert" appears and the application is installed, but when I uninstalled the application, and try again to install it, it shows me an error.

Why did this error happen?

> Error: Play Protect doesn't recognise this app's developer. Apps from unknown developers can sometimes be unsafe.

Comment: Did you find any solution i have same problem

Comment: Have you seen this? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080755/installation-app-blocked-by-play-protect

Answer (score 11):

I was having the same problem. I did some research and found this:

---

**Expiry of the debug certificate**

The self-signed certificate used to sign your app for debugging has an expiration date of 365 days from its creation date. When the certificate expires, you will get a build error.

To fix this problem, simply delete the debug.keystore file. The file is stored in the following locations:

- ~/.android/ **on OS X and Linux**
- C:\Documents and Settings\.android\ **on Windows XP**
- C:\Users\[user]\.android\ **on Windows Vista and Windows 7, 8, and 10**

The next time you build and run the debug build type, the build tools will regenerate a new keystore and debug key. Note that you must run your app, building alone does not regenerate the keystore and debug key.

---

It worked for me. The source of my information is the official android developers site: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Comment: Worked for me!!

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a little late but I had the same issue. Seems like it is caused by if you are using HTTPS URL in  API calls.
I have separate builds for PROD and DEBUG. On PROD I am using HTTPS and it works and on debug I used to have HTTP only and it used to work fine. Now since changing the API URL I am facing this issue.

Hope this helps!