# debug version of an apk got blocked by play services

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play, ionic4

I'm trying to build my app for developing purpose, It worked before but when I'm trying to build it on a new computer Google Play Protect blocks my app.

My application is build on Ionic 4, on a new computer (I develop it on another computer).

I tried to build it with debug option but it didn't work.

I did a research and found some answers, this was the most logical: [Debug app blocked by play protect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51344169/debug-app-blocked-by-play-protect)

I tried to delete the debug key from the `~/.android/` directory and after it didn't work I tried to delete all cache data from the `~/android/` directory.

I also saw this question [installation app blocked by play protect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080755/installation-app-blocked-by-play-protect) but he had problem with release apk and not with debug apk as I have.

How am I trying to build:

`ionic cordova build android --prod --debug`

After it didn't work I tried to clean my configuration:

`cordova clean`

didn't work either.

The error message that I get is that the app developer isn't recognize to google.

Expected result is: be able to install debug application for developing purpose.

Comment: Debug signingConfigs are machine specific. If you sign a debug apk on 2 computers you will end up with 2 apks that google thinks come from different sources. What you want is possible by creating a keystore file for debugging purposes and configure gradle to use that keystore in the debug buildtype. You will have to reinstall the current app first

Comment: @TimCastelijns I don't have the previous keystore, so I tried to install the app with `ionic run` it works, but I'm still unable to install it after build for the same reason.

Comment: Are you trying to update your app, I mean your app is available on play store?

Comment: @user9088454 No, I haven't published it yet. it still under development

Comment: then create a new ionic 4 project and put your src there and install the plugin if you added

Comment: for someone who will come here in the future, After all what I did I think I was needed a restart and that's was what let me install the app, I'm still getting the error on first installtion but now I can skip it and install it anyway

Comment: Btw: You can deploy the debug build to your own phone using the commandline. Connect the device via usb, and use `ionic cordova run android`