# Blocked by Play Protect [debug apk]

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, apk, google-play-protect

Is it necessary to have google-services.json in every single android project even if I don't want to opt for firebase BaaS or firebaseAuth? I am facing a problem. I am not able to install **app-debug.apk** on any android device and I am getting a warning message "**Blocked by Play Protect** Play Protect doesn't recognize this app's developer". I don't want to spend $25 to get registered as an android developer as I am just learning the app development. Please note I am not planning to release the app on Play Store. Is there any workaround? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debug app blocked by play protect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51344169/debug-app-blocked-by-play-protect)

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080755/installation-app-blocked-by-play-protect?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @RobertoManfreda I have setup android studio just 2-3 days ago and the debug.keystore is only 2 days old. I think the solution provided here[Debug app blocked by play protect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51344169/debug-app-blocked-by-play-protect) doesn't ease my trouble.

Comment: Did you tried to invalidate cache and restart? Then rebuild the project from build apk(s) entry

Comment: Are you using any other firebase dependencies?

Comment: Can you add your build.gradle?

Comment: @SarahKhan The problem was resolved. I had not signed the app! Thanks for concern.