# Released APK installed in Android Device is Error Blocked by Play Protect

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api

I have Generated signed Apk and installed in Android device its give Dialog for Blocked by Play Protect.when Debug app is installed in devices Successfully installed.

I have Used two Google `Api`. Map and `youtube` after i will use `firebase api`.

How to change Project code in Android Studio or Google `Api`, release `Apk` successfully installed.

[image]

dependency :-

```
[dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: \['*.jar'\], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-2-2-4.jar')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:3.0.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}



configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.0.1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [installation app blocked by play protect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080755/installation-app-blocked-by-play-protect)

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you communicate with Google will fix the problem. They have prepared a form for such situations. They usually correct within 3-5 days. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals?hl=en

or signing with a new developer account will fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Build a new key but make sure your are logged in to Android Studio. This fixed the issue for me.