# play protect does not recognize this app's developer

Tags: android, release, sign

I try to publish my app in a market that is not google play. When I try to install my app it says:

> Play Protect doesn't recognise this app's developer. Apps from unknown developers can sometimes be unsafe.

I think the problem may be from the sign of app. I get release with another app but the problem stays.
What is the problem? Is it because of I did not publish in google play? Or maybe from the sign? Or maybe in there somewhere in my code?

Comment: @mohammed khojaste please can you share with me how do you fix this issue

Comment: @pic you should enter your app detail in this link :https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals

Comment: Have you found the root cause for this issue?

Answer (score 6):

The Google app bundle format uses your certificate from the app as an upload certificate. Google generates a new certificate after upload that is used for app signing.
So since your app is not uploaded and published, there is no signing key, and app is blocked by play protect when you try to install it locally.

Comment: I upload my apk and it published on play store , but i faced with this problem

Answer (score 5):

I released 1.0 version earlier.
Now released 1.1 version.

1.0 before uploading on to Play console, I was able to install signed release apk, no issues.
1.1 before uploading on to Play console, I was - not - able to install signed release apk, and failed.

Looks like, play protect gives this error for an already released version on play store, if so, so this message should be seen as normal.

*Once the 1.1 is pushed to play store, I saw no issues*, so this error was just a false negative and can be ignored if you are updating the app.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes!**

Because you are not publish through Google Play Store and Google Play Protect uses the list of registered developers to identify the app installed.  Since you have not publish through play store before, you will always get that message.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I upload my apk and it published on play store , but i faced with this problem

Comment: @miladsalimi Did you resolve your issue? If so, Can you please tell me?

Comment: @Mighty , It takes little time  , if you ask somebodies add comments and rates its done faster.

Answer (score 1):

You will indeed have to upload your app to the google play store in order to eradicate this problem! Google has a list of verified developers who have already published their app to google play and thus they don't face any issues. Since you have not uploaded your app to google play, you will face the issue. What is happening is that google play protect is not able to recognize you as a developer as you have not uploaded your app to the google play store. Uploading your application to the google play store will help you get rid of this unrecognized message by google play protect.
Edit: Please Contact Google if you have any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Publish your App in Google Play to get rid of this error...

Comment: This is not an option when you live in Iran!

Comment: Also not an option if your dev account has been cancelled for other reason (which may be trivial).

Answer (score -1):

The problem is solved after publishing your application on Google Play Console.