# How to get the URL for my App's APK? (Google Play Protect appeal)

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I need to send some info to Google Play Protect as, while my app works fine on Google Play Store, it comes up with an error for those downloading it from the Samsung App Store.

One of the questions is the URL to download my APK. I've only ever uploaded signed APK's I have generated to the app stores. I have never used a URL so how would I get that for my app so I can fill in this question for the Google Play Protect team.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

finally, a link I tried worked and here is how to make it for FREE.

1. Make a DropBox Account
2. upload the apk to your DropBox Account
3. get the share link
4. Edit the link from “https://www.dropbox.com/s/example/app.apk?dl=0”
   to “https://www.dropbox.com/s/example/app.apk?dl=1” by changing the
   0 at the end to 1
5. you have successfully created an acceptable link.

update

after number 4 :

- drop the edited link in bit.ly to shorten it to like bit.ly/example

and use this for url

Comment: now i get this error from google:

You recently submitted an appeal for an app with Google Play Protect.

We were unable to download the APK file from the link you provided. Please submit a new appeal and make sure that the link is publicly browsable.

Comment: @Ali Yousefi this is work for me , try this several time

Comment: This is so bad! I tried a couple of other sites that provide direct download links but Google said it can't be downloaded. Googles algorithm written by interns maybe?! Finally the dropbox link worked. Thanks.

Comment: This worked. Tried every other link from firebase storage to self-hosted website. Nothing worked except dropbox with dl=1

Comment: Hmm, tries everything, also dropbox dl=1 and bitly. without success :-(

Comment: Can I give a link to an app bundle ?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using gitlab to host your project, and the project is public by default, you can enable access using gitlab link - just add a `?inline=false` at the end of the url.

example:

- my open-source project is at
  https://gitlab.com/reem.halamish/gatocaller
- the APK is at 
  https://gitlab.com/reem.halamish/gatocaller/-/raw/main/Android/app/beta/app-beta.apk
- the link I need is 
  https://gitlab.com/reem.halamish/gatocaller/-/raw/main/Android/app/beta/app-beta.apk?inline=false