# Blocked play protected when installing apk from build folder but working fine when running from android studio

Tags: android, google-play-protect

When i running my app from android studio it's working fine but when I'm installing from build folder then getting alert for Blocked Play Protected.
I have tried many solution from like deleting debug.keystore and many more

Comment: You need to build an apk for that. Build>Build APK. Don't generate a signed APK. You need debug.keystore only for signing the APK.

Comment: @sanjeev  I was doing the same.

Comment: Maybe this could be of some help https://stackoverflow.com/a/51233170/6514945