# Debug APK installation blocked by play protect

Tags: android, android-manifest, firebase-dynamic-links

After implements Firebase Dynamic Link in my project. When I run app from android studio its run but App not shown in App list.

If I try to install Debug APK , It show error : "**Play Protect doesn't recognise this app's developer. Apps from unknown developers can sometimes be unsafe.**"

I added this code in manifest file for Firebase Dynamic Link :

```
  <activity
            android:name=".Auth.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="MainActivity">
            <intent-filter android:label="MainActivity">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data
                    android:host="mydomain.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/post"
                    android:scheme="https" />
                <data
                    android:host="mydomain.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/post"
                    android:scheme="http" />

            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

**Update:**
and also when I removed this code from manifest It will work good.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080755/installation-app-blocked-by-play-protect

Comment: Hello Nilesh, This is not duplicate question. I can not find solution for this, Can you send me solution link?

Comment: Bali, My app not live on play store., I got error when debug apk install.

Answer (score 0):

try with Disabling `Play Protect` option in Play store app

To disable Google Play Protect.

- Open "Play Store" application
- tap on Menu button
- select "Play Protect" option
- Disable the options "Scan device for security threats".

**UPDATE**

this issue arise for local development with debug app but when you generate Signed apk this issue will may not arise. If still you get this issue then try with publish your app on play store and submit  [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals)

Till you may try with Disabling `Play Protect` option

Comment: It's temp. solution , I think same issue faced when I upload on play store.

Comment: @BhumikaP. check updated ans

Comment: Omik, How to solve debug apk issue?

Its not show in app list, how to test?

Comment: have tried with disabling `play protect` option?

Comment: Omik, I disabled Play protect , but still app not shown in app list.

Comment: @BhumikaP. instead of running app directly from studio try with install using build .apk  file from `Build > Build APK(s)`