# The application could not be installed: SHELL_UNRESPONSIVE -android studio 3.5

Tags: android, gradle, installation

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: SHELL_UNRESPONSIVE
The device timed out while trying to install the application.
Retry
```

This happens when trying to install APK on a real device. the installation start then
showing on real device  play protect prevention that the app is from unknown app's developer can harmful to your mobile.
showing to option below:
1.install anyway.
2.ok.

Comment: Look at Mostaf Azadi's answer here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080755/installation-app-blocked-by-play-protect

Comment: I restart my device and its work properly.

Answer (score -1):

It may because your phone memory is full. you can delete some data from your phone and then try. for me it worked.