# Android Studio signed apk not install and not display Admob ads

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, apk

I created an Android app and created Admob ads. While the app is running or installing it works without any problems, but when I sign the app and try to install it, the message appears as in the picture.

[image]

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I found a similar question (don't know duplicate or not): https://stackoverflow.com/q/51080755/3501958

Comment: Does this answer your question? [installation app blocked by play protect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080755/installation-app-blocked-by-play-protect)

Answer (score 0):

it was against the policy of play protect? so it is blocking to authenticate you.

Comment: i don't know policy of play protect?

Comment: Hey, it is better if you explain the policies to OP as well as it is pretty clear that there is a violation of a policy.