# How to test a built android application from github on a device?

Tags: android, signed-apk

I have cloned from github and made some changes in [K-9 Mail](https://github.com/k9mail/k-9) application. I was able to succeffully build a signed apk, but I can't test it on my device, because the installation is blocked by Play Protect. How can I deal with it? How can I test changes that I have made?

Comment: Have you tried following suggestions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080755/installation-app-blocked-by-play-protect?

Comment: @NickShebanov Yes, I have seen this. I have tried several suggestions from this topic, but without success. However I didn't try to send "Play Protect Appeals Submission Form", I don't know if it's appropriate in my case.

Answer (score 0):

what software did you use to compile the apk?  If you used Android Studio or Eclipse you should be able to use an emulator to test your apk file.

Comment: I have used Android Studio. So there is no way to test it on a device?

Comment: You should be able to test it on a device, I believe it's the Play Protect which is preventing you from doing so.  I guess you could temporarily disable Play Protect and then run the app on your device through Android Studio.  The other option would be to fill out the Ply Protect submission form  but then you may have to wait a few days.

Comment: I have disabled the Play Protect in my settings, but without success, the installation failed. I have tried several approaches without success from this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080755/installation-app-blocked-by-play-protect). However I didn't try to send "Play Protect Appeals Submission Form", I don't know if it's appropriate in my case, because I'm not an author of this application. Do you think that in my case it will be approriate?