# How to have Play Protect verified apps that are sideloaded in an app?

Tags: android, sideloading, google-play-protect

Is there a way to verify applications by Play Protect in order to be sideloaded by a main application?

The thing is that I have an app that allows employees to install other apps that are made by a company for internal use, but the problem is that whenever an app is downloaded and user tries to install it, Play Protect warning pops up and requires user interaction so the app can be installed. For some employees this is very complicated and I need to solve this problem.

Can somebody advise how can I verify apps by Play Protect and allows user to install an application like it's downloaded from Play Store?

I know that is possible, because Galaxy Store is actually third party PlayStore, but can you help me to learn how can I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: I assume those internal apps need to be verified by play protect first and then can be sideloaded without issue? Check this form here https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals which I got from this link https://stackoverflow.com/q/51080755/1133011

Comment: @DavidKroukamp That is correct. Thank you very much, I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: Glad to hear it will mark this as a duplicate then