# Installing apk but blocked by Google Play Protect

Tags: apk, google-play-protect

I am developing a dating app which is for the LGBTQ group.
Due to our target users mainly from China and their local brands using their own App stores, most of them did not have Google Play on their devices. So we provide an APK for our users to install the App.
However, there are still little parts of users who use devices that have Google Play.
Recently, when users install our APK, their device always shows a warning: "Unsafe app blocked", which does not happen before.
The fully message:
`Play Protect doesn't recognise this app's developer. Apps from unknown developers can sometimes be unsafe.`

I've tried to change the package name and app signature key, but it still not works. And we are not going to submit our app to Google Play for their review, because as you know the user of dating apps may post some "sensitive" photos or videos, I think it would be a reason to block our app again...
Could anybody know how to deal with the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [installation app blocked by play protect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080755/installation-app-blocked-by-play-protect)

Comment: I'm afraid not. We don't want to submit the app to Google Play for their review, because users of dating apps may post some "sensitive" photos or videos, and I don't think they will agree with that.

Comment: You could try to publish a different app signed with the same signature key in PlayStore. That would allow Google to lern that the key belongs to you, and may be this also have an effect on your non-PlayStore-published apps, as a cryptographically signing key can not be faked...

Comment: Thank you @Robert. I will try your method, let's see how it goes.

Comment: Is your problem solved? If yes then how?

Comment: @Cheng-ChongTang please let us know the way you solved this